# Is there a way to add macro definition to MonoDevelop?

Tags: macros, mono

I need a special keyword in my code to be replaced by a consequence of symbols before the build.

For example, I want hello to be replaced by Debug.Log("Hello");

According to [this](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/questions-about-MonoDevelop-td1510303.html), MonoDevelop didn't have this feature in 2006. Has anything changed?

If no, are there any plugins/external tools implementing it?

I don't think that switching to another IDE will be helpful unless it can use code completion for unity3d.

Please, don't answer that macro definitions are evil.

---

Update:
I understood that my example was too abstract. In fact, I want to replace read("name"); with

```
var name;
name=gameObject.Find("name");
if(!name)
    return;
name=name.param;
```

Comment: This is not answer to your question but it might solve your problem:
#if DEBUG
Debug.Log("Hello");
#endif
Notice that this won't have any performance penalty in release.

Comment: This will require to duplicate the defined command and make it hard to edit.

Comment: Sounds like "#if DEBUG" should be inside Debug.Log() method.

Comment: In this case, yes. I updated the answer.

Comment: I still think that you should create method called"private string FindName(string str)" which has #if SOMETHING. Because from what I understand you want to do some macro that applies at compile time which is IDE specific? How do you plan to teach CI to apply that macro or if someone decides to do it in SharpDevelop or Notepad...

Comment: I am planning to edit this code myself and can use a specific IDE. Called methods cannot stop callers from execution and create variables, can they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Every script should have all needed variables declared + a variable called "self".

2)They should be public.

3)

```
public static function set_var(target,name:String,value)
{
    var fi=typeof(target).GetField(name);
    fi.SetValue(target,value);
}
public static function read(name:String,target):String
{
    set_var(target,"self",target);
    return "var rtmp=self.gameObject.GetComponent(\""+name+"\");"+"if(!rtmp)return;"+name+"=rtmp.param;"; 
}
```

4)`eval(read("name",this));`

5)As far as I know, it wouldn't work in  unity C#

---

6)Probably, set_var can be replaced by assignment

---

Far better solution:

```
    var component_names = ["hello","thing","foo"];

    var component;
    for(var name:String in component_names)
    {
        component = gameObject.GetComponent(name);
        if(!component)
            return;
        set_var(this,name,component.param);
    }
```

(Requires set_var() from the first one)